# Save mongoose schema to MYSQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, mongoose

Hey I'm writing discord oauth2 app for my panel. I have a problem here because the `passport` library is prepared for MongoDB, and I prefer to use MYSQL.

`(Part of the code is missing but it is irrelevant)`

```
passport.use(new DiscordStrategy({
    clientID: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
    callbackURL: process.env.CLIENT_REDIRECT,
    scope: ['identify', 'email', 'guilds']
}, async (acessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
    done(null, user)
}))
```

The problem here is with the `done` function, since it must take a `user` argument, it is a schema from `mongoose`.

Can I create some schema using MYSQL or can I save mongoose schema in MYSQL and how to do it?

Please help and thank you.

Comment: Passport doesn't know or care what database you use, where did you see anything about having to use MongoDB? In the function there, you can store the user in whatever database you want, however you want to do it. Passport doesn't care.

Comment: ok but can i save the mongoose schema in mysql?

Comment: No, and you don't need to. This has nothing to do with mongoose. The `user` argument has nothing to do with mongoose. You seem to be under a misconception about that. Mongoose is not involved here.